# Finding the Polar Equation of a line

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hello, this problem is giving me some trouble. I'm confused as to how I find the equation of the line. I know that $x^2+y^2=r^2$, $x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$, and that $\tan(\theta)=\frac{y}{x}$. I'm just unsure as to how I can derive the polar equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the line is given by $19x + 3y = 19(-19) + 3(-3) = -370$ and so we have $19x + 3y + 370 = 0$ without much work.

So we have $r(19\cos(\theta) + 3\sin(\theta)) = -370$, which implies $r = \frac{-370}{19\cos(\theta) + 3\sin(\theta)}$.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of the circle is $$x^2+y^2=370$$ Differentiating implicitly, we find $$2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ so $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$$So the slope of your line is $-\frac{19}{3}$. Therefore, in Cartesian coordinates, the slope of the line is $$y=-\frac{19}{3}(x+19)-3$$Now substitute $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ and solve for $r$.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use calculus, you can use a little elementary geometry: tangents are perpendicular to radii drawn to the point of tangency. Here, the slope of the line containing the radius from $(-19,-3)$ is obviously $\frac{3}{19}$, and perpendicular lines have slopes that are negative reciprocals, so the slope of the tangent line is $-\frac{19}{3}$.